# Membership status rules not updating statuses

Tags: civimember

Hoping someone can see what we are doing wrong here.  We have four membership status rules:

1. Current - (Start Event = start date, End Event = end date)
2. Grace - January (Start Event = end date, End Event = end date + 1 month)
3. Lapsed - February & March (Start Event = end date + 1 month, End Event = end date + 3 months)
4. Not Renewed - April onwards (Start Event = end date + 3 months, End Event = nothing set as this is a permanent non renewal)

1, 2 and 3 working fine, but now that we are in April, status is showing as 'lapsed' still, rather than 'not renewed'.  We've run the cron job to update status, no change.

Comment: What status have you set the lapsed membership to? If its not current then in effect CiviCRM wont touch it from that point onwards (I dont think!). Seems like your treating Lapsed as an extension of Grace?

Comment: Lapsed is set as a current membership and yes - it is an extension of Grace but members who are Lapsed have less privileges in the organisation. 

One odd thing.. we have three members showing correctly as 'not renewed' - all three had tried to renew earlier in the year but transaction hadn't completed or they had opted for 'pay later'

Comment: Ok, maybe set the Not Renewed status rule to use start date = start date and set the end date rule to + 3 months? Thats the only thing I can think is perhaps causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks Parvez. Tried that. No change.