# Membership status rules query

Tags: civimember

This is a follow-up from a previous question that we couldn't find a resolution for ([Membership status rules not updating statuses](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/35319/membership-status-rules-not-updating-statuses?noredirect=1#comment40847_35319)).

We have three status rules once a membership has not been renewed - Grace, Lapsed and Not Renewed. 'Not Renewed' is an extension of Lapsed and we consider it more permanent than lapsed and cannot target those members again unless they get in touch due to data protection/spam etc.

The issue was that membership status of those members more than 3 months past end date did not get updated to 'Not renewed' and stayed at lapsed.  Thought this was maybe just a limitation of the number of 'lasped' membership status you could have.  However, checking today, I see a small number of membership statuses have updated to 'not renewed'. In all cases, there was a failed PayPal transaction so the contribution is still pending.

Able to add pictures of the rules this time for clarity. Anyone have any ideas what we're doing wrong?

Thanks for your time :-)

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is similar to what Parvez describes with a slight twist. I think it is the fact that you renamed Expired to be Lapsed, and the system is set up so that once it is Expired it will not progress based on the rules.

So if you create a new Lapsed one, or switch your Lapsed and Not Renewed around you might find it starts working.

I.e. the original 'expired' has special properties and hence should be the last one in the automated statuses.

Comment: Good catch Pete, that may well be the issue - all I know is theres a lot of hidden features regards expired/non current members!

Comment: Thank you both so much. Swapping them around appears to have sorted it for us :-)
Will see what happens in January when 'grace' & 'lapsed' come back into play!

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I thought I'd answered previously but I'm 99% this is down to the fact that once a membership status becomes ended the automated rules then wont touch it. So the first status of type ended in theory would be the one that gets applied and any subsequent ones wouldn't be something that automatically gets moved on. I'm 99% thats the issue your facing, a previous question asked if CiviRules could be used to change membership statuses (which it cant yet), your case is probably one that fits a CiviRules status change I think. Let me know if you prove the theory!

Comment: Thanks Parvez. What do you mean by 'becomes ended'?  Both grace and lapsed are current memberships, 'not renewed' is the first status that we have configured to not be current.

Comment: Each status has a "Member" flag of yes or no. I think the first status with a "No" is the one that will get set. When CiviCRM then re-runs its status rules it excludes any that are "No" type membership statuses (I think) and therefore your members never move onto other statuses. Like I say its a theory but I know that CiviCRM often excludes lapsed members from processes and I'm pretty sure thats the reason.